# Level traversing to print a BST using array of pointers.

Tags: c

I'm trying to traverse level by level through a tree to print it. Instead of creating a copy of the tree, I need to use only a dynamic array of pointers to the tree. It's been now 4 hours as I'm a beginner and I couldn't put my finger on the reason behind the segmentation fault. I apologise if the bug is kind of easy to spot or if this is not worth posting:

```
typedef struct bst{
    int value; 
    struct bst* right; 
    struct bst* left; 
}BSTn;                //Binary Search Tree node

//Prototype: 
int height(BSTn* b);
void insert(BSTn** root, int value); 
void print(BSTn* b); 

void print(BSTn* b){
    BSTn** level_pointers =  (BSTn**)malloc( sizeof(BSTn*));
    level_pointers[0] = b;                 //Copy of the pointer to the root
    int level_pointers_len = 1;    //Initial length of the array of pointers
    int new_level_index;                                    
    int new_level_len;
    BSTn** new_level = (BSTn**) malloc(2*level_pointers_len* sizeof(BSTn*));  
    //Each new level is max twice the previous

    while(1){

        new_level_index = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < level_pointers_len; i++){
            printf("%i \t", level_pointers[i]->value);  
            if (level_pointers[i]->left != NULL){
                new_level[new_level_index] = level_pointers[i]->left; 
                new_level_index ++; 
            }
            if (level_pointers[i]->right != NULL){
                new_level[new_level_index] = level_pointers[i]->right; 
                new_level_index ++; 
            }

        printf("\n"); 
        }
        if (new_level_index == 0) 
            return; 
        new_level_len = new_level_index + 1; 
        level_pointers = (BSTn**)realloc(new_level, new_level_len*sizeof(BSTn*)); 
        new_level = (BSTn**) malloc(2*level_pointers_len* sizeof(BSTn*)); 
        level_pointers_len = new_level_len; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a copy of the pointers, in order to traverse?

Comment: Is your real problem the actual breadth-first traversal? Because such a traversal is commonly done via an intermediate *queue*. The basic algorithm is (a) push the non-null root node on the queue, then (b) repeat the following until there are no nodes in the queue. 1. If the queue is empty, you're done, otherwise pop off a node,  2. process it, and finally 3. push its non-null children in consistent order (always push left first, then right, for example). Repeat at (b). It's a pretty standard algorithm.